# Expected value of function of exponential random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $X \sim Exp(\lambda)$ (exponential distribution) and $Y=X^a$. For what  values of $a\in R$ is $E[Y]< \infty$?

I computed $E[Y] = \lambda \int x^a e^{-\lambda x}dx$. How to proceed? Does the answer depend on $\lambda$?

Comment: I think the answer is  for $a>-1$

Answer (score 1):

Well, using the definition of Gamma function, we can see that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[Y] =\frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\lambda^{a}}.
\end{equation}

Next, using Prym's decomposition of Gamma function, we know that
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(a)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(z+n)}+\int_{1}^{\infty} x^{a-1}{\rm e}^{-x}{\rm d} x.
\end{equation}
Hence, $\Gamma(a)$ has simple poles on negative integer.

Moreover, for negative non-integer numbers, you can easily see that the series is absolutely convergent (take a look at the definition of exponential series).

Comment: For what values of $a$ would $\Gamma(a)$ be well-defined? What happens when $a < 0$?

Comment: You were correct. Just edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

You are correct in that $$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \lambda \int_0^\infty x^a e^{-\lambda x}dx$$ and since you need $\mathbb{E}[Y] < \infty$, you are looking for a range of $a$ for which
the integral converges.

Let's first play with a simple case of $\lambda = 1$, we are looking for $\int_0^\infty x^a e^{-x} dx$, which has 2 potential problems, at $x = 0$ if $a < 0$ and at $x \to \infty$. So we can write
$$
\int_0^\infty x^a e^{-x} dx = \int_0^1 x^a e^{-x} dx + \int_1^\infty x^a e^{-x} dx.
$$

Let's deal with the problem at $x \to \infty$ first, so look at the second integral. For any value of $a$ and $x$ large enough, you can bound the integrand by $1/x^2$ (can you prove it?) and the integral would converge.

For the first integral, we have a problem when $a < 0$. Can you finish the analysis for this case and generalize for other $\lambda > 0$?

**UPDATE**

For the second integral, if we want to bound
$$
x^ae^{-x} < x^{-2} \iff \frac{x^{2+a}}{e^x} < 1
$$
What is the limit of the LHS as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I have no idea how to show that the second integrand is bounded by $1/x^2$ although I can see why we may want to show that ($\int_1^{\infty} 1/x^2 dx = 1$). Any further tips would be helpful.

Comment: @ForumWhiner added an update for that one. Can you finish the analysis?

Comment: The issue is that I do not know how to show $x^c$ grows faster/slower than $e^x$ in general for any constant $c \in \mathcal{R} $. Using L'hopital rule is leading me nowhere!

Comment: @ForumWhiner consider the Taylor series for $e^x$ around $0$, which includes expansion of all integer powers of $x$... Alternatively, take logs and show $c \ln x < x$

Comment: Ok, and how does one use it to check $x^{2+a}/e^x <1$?

Comment: @ForumWhiner since exp is an increasing function, $x \ln x < x \iff x^c = e^{c \ln x} < e^x$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

**(1)** $a\leq-1$

$\int_0^{1}  x^{a}e^{-x} dx$ diverges.

Since For $0<x\leq 1$ 
 $$e^{-x}\geq e^{-1} \hspace{.5cm} and  \hspace{.5cm} x^{a} \geq x^{-1}$$
so
$$\int_0^{1}  x^{a}e^{-x} dx \geq \int_0^{1} e^{-1} x^a dx \geq \int_0^{1} e^{-1} \frac{1}{x} dx  $$  and 
$\int_0^{1} \frac{1}{x} dx $ diverges.

**(2)** For $a>-1$

$$\int_0^{+\infty}  x^{a}e^{-x} dx=\int_0^{+\infty}  x^{(a+1) -1}e^{-x} dx=\Gamma(a+1)$$
see [Incomplete_gamma_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

[Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) is also useful. 
For $k>0$ (equal with a>-1) and $\lambda>0$

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\lambda^k }{\Gamma(k)} x^{k-1}e^{-\lambda x} dx=1$$

so for any $k>0$

$$\int_0^{+\infty} x^{k-1}e^{-\lambda x} dx= \frac{\Gamma(k)}{\lambda^k}$$